# Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.1.0

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven, ojdbc

I am trying to add dependency for ojdbc14 in `pom.xml`.
Steps I followed for adding ojdbc14.jar in local repository of maven:

1. Create a new project
2. move to that particular folder where is pom.xml file was located in command prompt.
3. execute the command `mvn clean`.
4. execute the command:

   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=oracle -Dversion=10.2.0.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true

after this I got a build success message

I have updated the global and local repository in Eclipse > Maven Repositories

```
C:\> mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Users\Dhia\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\ojdb
c14.jar" -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.1.0 -Dpackag
ing=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom
---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Dhia\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\ojdbc14.jar to C:\Users\
Dhia\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.1.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.460s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 28 22:44:13 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\>
```

my local repoitory is C:\Users\Dhia\Desktop\eclipse jee
and when opening .com in eclipse oracle repository doesn't appear

when adding 
     
                com.oracle
                ojdbc14
                10.2.0.1.0

my pom.txt

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>b</groupId>
  <artifactId>b</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>b</name>
  
    <repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
 <!--      
 <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>  
   --> 
  </repositories>
  
  <dependencies>
  
  
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

I got error in my pom.xml file :Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.1.0, and I am not able to see the ojdbc14.jar file in my local repository. Is there any thing wrong in the steps I followed. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Show your pom file please.

Answer (score 16):

This can't be directly install because Oracle has put some license and agreements. So we have to download it manually and install it to the project. [Use this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html) to choose the version you need and download the ojdbc14.jar file. You must have an Oracle account to download it.

Then open the command prompt. Go to the file download location. Then enter below code.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.x.x.x -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Fill the x using your needed version. Then right click on your project >Maven>Update Project.

This will solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to the statement you have made about "because Oracle has put some license and agreements"? I'd like to pass that information on.

Answer (score 3):

The XML for version com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.1.0 is missing from the central repository.
So i think this version will create problem for many more people

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc14/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output of `mvn install:install-file`, the `jar` was correctly installed in your local maven repository. If you add this to your `pom.xml` (inside the `<dependencies>` section), your project should find the jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're still experiencing problems,
please share your `pom.xml` and the error output.

Comment: i added this dependency to my pom.txt but still the same problem

Comment: What error message do you get? (include it in your question text)

Comment: If you open a command line terminal, `cd` to your project directory, and do `mvn compile`, does that work?

Comment: Then please edit into your question the content of your `pom.xml`, and the output of the `mvn compile` command.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such artifact in maven central repository: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.4.0 (only pom).

Please refer [Is there an issue with the oracle dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007009/is-there-an-issue-with-the-oracle-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

Manually downloading the ojdbc14 jar worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of your maven `settings.xml` file. If you don't configure your local repo in `settings.xml` maven default repo will be  `Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository`. And you need to configure same maven settings in your IDE.

[See more details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41513401/6822868)