# Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0 ?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, ubuntu-14.04, ojdbc

I know this question has been asked several times.Even i have successfully done this in WINDOWS.But installed ubuntu OS and all set up is done except this.

Here are the following things i did.I Have oracle 11g i downloaded ojdbc6.jar,Installed Maven and run following command

```
sudo mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/nawaz/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

---

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] pom.xml not found in ojdbc6.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/nawaz/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.545 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-15T17:48:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and in .m2 directory
    `ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar.lastUpdated  ojdbc6-11.2.0.pom.lastUpdated`    I cleaned the mvn -U clean and Update nothing works..Hope someone can find the BUG :)

Comment: can you try to delete These files `ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar.lastUpdated  ojdbc6-11.2.0.pom.lastUpdated ` and try it again?

Comment: I tried now i dont see those files only after running mvn command also i used rm -rf ojdbc :P

Comment: Now i see the same files installed but error remains the same :'(

Comment: I dont know Y i just copied repository/com/oracle folder from windows to ubuntu it FIXED :D

Comment: Does you use `sudo` for building project?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I resolved this issue by checking my maven `settings.xml` file. My maven local repository is the place where I installed `ojdbc6.jar`. And when I tried to build my project using eclipse, the maven repository used by eclipse is different. This is causing the problem. I updated maven settings in eclipse and then it's worked fine for me.

To change the maven repo path in eclipse

```
1.Windows --> preferences    
2. Maven --> User Settings    
3. And in right side window update the settings
```

It looks like this:

[image: maven setting]

Comment: Even though we update the maven installation in eclipse...there is still the settings.xml being picked from default path...wonder why eclipse guys put the config there