# Build failing on maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have faced with a problem, that my build is crashing on maven 3.5.0 version.

I have some stack trace here :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) on project mdw: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0, com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0 from/to maven-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1/): Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1/ with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1/ with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) on project mdw: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0, com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0 from/to maven-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1/): Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1/ with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

Could anybody please help with this problem ?

Comment: `Could not transfer artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0`. AFAIK, Oracle does not push its JDBC artifacts on Maven Central. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007009/is-there-an-issue-with-the-oracle-dependency

Comment: Your pom.xml would also help here. Do you explicitly have the repository at http://download.java.net/maven/1/ listed in your pom.xml?